# Reading Matrix from file

Tags: python, numpy, file, matrix, spyder

I have a txt file consisting some numbers with space and I want to make it as three 4*4 matrixes in python. Each matrix is also divided with two symbols in the text file. The format of the txt file is like this:

```
1 1
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
1 1
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
1 1
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

My code is now like this but it is not showing the output I want.

```
file = open('inputs.txt','r')
a=[]
for line in file.readlines():
    a.append( [ int (x) for x in line.split('1 1') ] )
```

Can you help me with that?

Comment: What is the meaning of lines with `1 1`, do they separate matrixes?

Comment: The format of the output needs to be a three 4*4 array(matrixes) using numpy. 1 1 is the separation of the matrixes

Comment: you should rather read all - `read()` and later split it with `split('1 1')` to create 4 strings with matrixes. And later you would have to split these strings using `"\n"` and `space`.

Comment: maybe first ise `print()` to see what you get in `line` and `line.split('1 1')` and `x` (before you use `int()`. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing.

Comment: Storing the whole file into memory is not recommended. It might be terabytes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good old pure python algorithm (assuming matrices can hold string values, otherwise, convert as required):

```
file = open("inputs.txt",'r')
matrices=[]
m=[]
for line in file:
   if line=="1 1\n": 
      if len(m)>0: matrices.append(m)
      m=[]
   else:
      m.append(line.strip().split(' '))
if len(m)>0: matrices.append(m)
print(matrices)
# [[['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0']], 
#  [['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0']], 
#  [['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0']]]
```

Comment: How can I make it three 4*4 matrixes? For example writing the first row in a 4*4 matrix? I want them to be shown not right to each other but like 4 different lines under each other

Comment: There are no such things as matrixes in python. Only lists. You might want to look at numpy for examples, but I don't know exactly what you need. BTW screen output is independent of storage in memory.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `groupby`:

```py
from itertools import groupby

matrices = []

with open('inputs.txt', 'r') as f:
    for separator, lines in groupby(f, lambda line: line.strip() == '1 1'):
        if not separator:
            matrices.append([[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in lines])

print(matrices)
# [[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
#  [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
#  [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

Comment: How can I make it three 4*4 matrixes? For example writing the first row in a 4*4 matrix? I want them to be shown not right to each other but like 4 different lines under each other

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file is not humongous, it is numerical and 4x4, the easiest method is:

- read all the file
- split it in blocks with the `1 1\n` separator
- discard the separator items (`if block`)
- convert block to vector with `split`
- reshape each vector to 4x4
- make it integer

In a single line:
`matrixes = [np.reshape(np.array(block.split()),(4,4)).astype(int) for block in open('inputs.txt').read().split('1 1\n') if block]`

**Caveat**: if a matrix reads `x x 1 1` in one of its rows, it will be considered a split regardless. Using a value that could be used in the matrix is not a good idea.

That could be prevented splitting on `\n1 1\n`, and removing by hand the first 4 characters (`1 1\n`). Also this implementation may be more efficient, flattening everything and then reshaping:

```py
dd = open('inputs.txt').read()[4:]
nmats = dd.count('\n1 1\n') +1
matrixes = np.reshape(np.array(dd.replace('\n1 1\n',' ').split()).astype(int),(nmats,4,4))
```

This last option returns it as a single 3D matrix:

```
>>> matrixes
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]])
>>> matrixes[0]
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```